# How to control (unwanted) files being open by default after each turn on of pc?

Tags: kde, stickynotes

I have hundreds of KNotes which are open and displayed after each restart of pc. I've never asked for that and it's quiet bothering to close them one by one. Is there any way to control programs being open after each restart of pc ? I have the same issue for skype. But let's say that closing skype is not difficult but closing manually 120 KNotes is very bothering.  [image: fig1]

Comment: I do not know KDE, but that may be related to session management: perhaps your session is saved. Then, restarting the system reopens all windows that were open when you closed. Alternatively, you may need to look for the settings of the KNotes program.

Comment: No, they were not open when I turn off the computer. And that is the problem. 120 empty sticky notes are open after each restart of pc.